# Pass __init__ argument and use it as variable within the class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to call an AWS IoT call method with three given `__init__` arguments. But somehow the arguments were not able to be pass into the class itself. As you see from the given screenshot, the variable `ENDPOINT` was not found within the class. Any help will be highly appreciated.

#### testing.py

```
import AWS_Publishing

AWSEndPoint = "ak2faelus7i02-ats.iot.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
AWSClientId = ""


publishMessage = AWS_Publishing(AWSEndPoint, AWSClientId, "Test")

publishMessage
```

#### AWS_Publishing.py

```
from awscrt import io, mqtt, auth, http
from awsiot import mqtt_connection_builder
import time as t
import json

class AWS_Publishing:
    def __init__(self, endpoint, client_id, topic):
        self.ENDPOINT = endpoint
        self.CLIENT_ID = client_id
        self.TOPIC = topic

    PATH_TO_CERT = "certs/device.pem.crt"
    PATH_TO_KEY = "certs/private.pem.key"
    PATH_TO_ROOT = "certs/Amazon-root-CA-1.pem"
    MESSAGE = "Hello World"
    RANGE = 20


# Spin up resources
    event_loop_group = io.EventLoopGroup(1)
    host_resolver = io.DefaultHostResolver(event_loop_group)
    client_bootstrap = io.ClientBootstrap(event_loop_group, host_resolver)
    mqtt_connection = mqtt_connection_builder.mtls_from_path(
        endpoint=ENDPOINT,
        cert_filepath=PATH_TO_CERT,
        pri_key_filepath=PATH_TO_KEY,
        client_bootstrap=client_bootstrap,
        ca_filepath=PATH_TO_ROOT,
        client_id=CLIENT_ID,
        clean_session=False,
        keep_alive_secs=6
    )
```

to pass 'endpoint' into 'ENDPOINT'

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srZc9.png)

Comment: Python is case sensitive. Your parameter name is `endpoint` and the variable you are assigning is `ENDPOINT`. Those are 2 different variables. Additionally you are importing the module `AWS_Publishing` and then trying to call it directly. you would need to call the class within the module. So `AWS_Publishing.AWS_Publishing(*args)`.

Comment: You're trying to access `ENDPOINT` in the class' scope. But `ENDPOINT` is an **instance** variable , accessed via `self.ENDPOINT`... Did you mean for your whole code to be indented under the `__init__`? Otherwise it's not very clear

Comment: Hi. I am trying to call `AWS_Publishing(AWSEndPoint, AWSClientId, "Test")` in testing.py and using the arguments within the class itself. For example, `AWSEndPoint` will be used in the `mqtt_connection_builder.mtls_from_path( endpoint=ENDPOINT ...`. i have tried to use `self.ENDPOINT` but it also throws an error. :(

Comment: I have added a screenshot maybe it will be much clearer as to what I wanted to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: All that `mqtt_connection = ...` code is running at *class declaration time*, way before you do `AWS_Publishing(AWSEndPoint, ...)`. You'll want to indent all that code to be in some *method of the class* which you call after instantiating the class.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for your help. I managed to somehow solve the issue. Instead of creating a class, I created a function.

### testing.py

```
import AWS_Publishing

AWSEndPoint = "ak2faelus7i02-ats.iot.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
AWSClientId = "test"
Topic = "Testing"

publishAWS = AWS_Publishing.publish(AWSEndPoint, AWSClientId, Topic)

publishAWS
```

### AWS_Publishing.py

```
from awscrt import io, mqtt, auth, http
from awsiot import mqtt_connection_builder
import time as t
import json

def publish(ENDPOINT, CLIENT_ID, TOPIC):
    PATH_TO_CERT = "certs/device.pem.crt"
    PATH_TO_KEY = "certs/private.pem.key"
    PATH_TO_ROOT = "certs/Amazon-root-CA-1.pem"
    MESSAGE = "Hello World"
    RANGE = 20

    event_loop_group = io.EventLoopGroup(1)
    host_resolver = io.DefaultHostResolver(event_loop_group)
    client_bootstrap = io.ClientBootstrap(event_loop_group, host_resolver)
    mqtt_connection = mqtt_connection_builder.mtls_from_path(
        endpoint=ENDPOINT,
        cert_filepath=PATH_TO_CERT,
        pri_key_filepath=PATH_TO_KEY,
        client_bootstrap=client_bootstrap,
        ca_filepath=PATH_TO_ROOT,
        client_id=CLIENT_ID,
        clean_session=False,
        keep_alive_secs=6
    )
    print("Connecting to {} with client ID '{}'...".format(
        ENDPOINT, CLIENT_ID))
    # Make the connect() call
    connect_future = mqtt_connection.connect()
    # Future.result() waits until a result is available
    connect_future.result()
    print("Connected!")
    # Publish message to server desired number of times.
    print('Begin Publish')
    for i in range(RANGE):
        data = "{} [{}]".format(MESSAGE, i + 1)
        message = {"message": data}
        mqtt_connection.publish(topic=TOPIC, payload=json.dumps(
            message), qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
        print("Published: '" + json.dumps(message) +
              "' to the topic: " + TOPIC)
        t.sleep(0.1)
    print('Publish End')
    disconnect_future = mqtt_connection.disconnect()
    disconnect_future.result()
```

Comment: I like that you got to this solution because there is a tendency to newcomers to Python to use alot of classes. Maybe because in Java for example everything is classes... In Python classes are not always necessary - just as in your case. Using a function seems much more appropriate